# Bug for simple quotation marks in connection to database

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string, sqlconnection

I have the following code to add a new user:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public class users
{

    public Sqlconnection myconn ()
    {
        return new ("data source=.; integrated security=true; initial catalog=test;");
    } 

    public bool insertuser(username, pass, type)
    {
        try {
            string query="insert into users (username, pass, type) values ( '"+username+"', '"+pass+"', '"+type+"');
            return true;
            SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand (query, this.myconn);
            mycommand.Connection.Open();
            mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mycommand.Connection.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

now in the form if user calls to this method

```
users user1 = new users();

if(user1.insertuser(txtusername.tex, txtpass.text, cbtype.text)==true)
{
    // BUG IS HERE IF USER WRITE  SOMETHING SO..   ANGEL'   (WITH THIS ')
    // MY CODE IS GOING TO HAVE A  BUG!
    // I QUIT THEM IN KEY PRESS BUT WHAT HAPPEND IF USERS MUST TO ADD SOMETHING AS
    // tic's 
    // what can i do for my code acept all?? and it doesn't have any bug?
    MessageBox.show("user added");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one issue with your code:

- the second line in your code sample is `return true;`, which means it will not run anything
- method parameters in InsertUsers do not have type specified
- don't keep connection open, dispose connection after data are retrieved
- use `using` to guarantee connection closing/disposal even if exception happened
- use parametrized query. Find here why: [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
- don't catch all exceptions, SqlException only in this case

Tried to make it from scratch:

```
public static bool InsertUser(string userName, string password, string type)
{
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.; integrated security=true; initial catalog=test;"))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "insert into users (username, pass, type) values (@username, @password, @type)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", userName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", password);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("type", type);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've rediscovered SQL injection attacks.

**Don't include externally-derived values in your SQL.**

Use parameterized queries instead.

The code you've shown wouldn't compile anyway (Sqlcommand vs SqlCommand) but read [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx) (or just search for information on parameterized queries or SQL injection) for more information.

Comment: That first line made me chuckle

Comment: @angel: So that means it's not your real code - so we don't know whether the bug is also in your real code. Why didn't you cut and paste real code?

Comment: @Jon because this is not a very important problem, i solve it with key press, but now i want to know how to allow>>> (') <<<that

Comment: @angel: No, it's an *incredibly* important problem. Do you really want users to be able to delete all your data, for example?

Comment: delete all my information? how? writting .. 'delete from users' ? mmm i hadn't thouth that

Comment: for that in key press i quit users aren't going to be able to write ' or "

Comment: @angel: You'd better hope there's nothing else that you haven't thought of then... fundamentally, you really need to look into SQL injection attacks. This is a well-known area, and constructing SQL statements by including externally-derived data is a well-known bad practice, with a simple fix: parameterized SQL.